# Error: request for member 'time_c' in something not a structure or union in C language

Tags: c, pointers, struct, request, union

I have a problem with some of my functions. I want to get a member ob a struct, out of another struct. The normal call is functionel, but embedded in a function, it doesn't work. Is there any idea why and how I can solve that?

The following function is an example. It should get the time out of a struct, embedded in another struct via the time-converting function "FUN_1"

```
FUN_1((time_t *)&ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries->s_28b_meta->time_c);
```

My structs are:

```
struct s_28b_meta {
    int version;
    __time32_t time_c;
    __time32_t time_m;
    uint32_t i_next;
    int hash_value;
    int len_database_name;
    int *ptr_database_name;
};

struct s_20b_parse_entries {
    int *s_28b_meta;
    int *s_8b_keys;
    int **a_db_entries;
    size_t n_db_entries;
    int i_next;
};
```

The decleration:

```
struct s_28b_meta *ptr_temp;
struct s_20b_parse_entries *ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries;
```

Comment: Variable names are not type names.

Comment: The declaration of `ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries` doesn't seem posted here. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry, I edited it.

Comment: And where is "a struct, embedded in another struct"?

Comment: you are right. They are more pointing to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `struct s_20b_parse_entries`, you have the `s_28b_meta` field defined as `int *`.  This is not a pointer to struct so you can't use the `->` operator on it, which is why you're getting the error.

It should be defined as a `struct s_28b_meta *`.

Comment: Thank you. With  struct s_28b_meta* s_28b_meta; it worked!